# List of dictionaries: loop through key contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, data-structures

I apologize for the seemingly confusing title, hope the code will help clarify the question.

I have a python data structure that looks like this:

```py
people = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Ada',
    'age': 55
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Bart',
    'age': 46
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Chloe',
    'age': 37
  },
  {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Dylan',
    'age': 28
  }
]
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
1, Ada, 55
2, Bart, 46
3, Chloe, 37
4, Dylan, 28
```

Without having to address each dictionary key like `person['key']` but rather by just `key`; something like this:

```py
# BOGUS CODE, WON'T WORK
for (id, name, age) in people:
  print('{}, {}, {}'.format(id, name, age))
```

(which curiously prints `name, id, age`)
Thanks in advance!

PS: Bonus question! Is there a specific name for list/arrays of homogeneous dictionaries/objects (also outside of Python)? *List of homogenous dictionaries* seems quite a mouthful.

Comment: `print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(id, name, age))` ?

Comment: @Mika72, This won't work, notice that OP is iterating over a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `for dict_ in people: print("{id}, {name}, {age}".format(**dict_))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
for person in people:
    person_id, name, age = person['id'], person['name'], person['age']
    print(person_id, name, age)
```

In Python 3.6 (officially supported from 3.7) you could also do (provided that values are defined exactly in the same order you shown us in the original question):

```
for person in people:
    person_id, name, age = person.values()
    print(person_id, name, age)
```

However, this relies on the fact that the dictionary is defined **exactly** as it is in your example. If the order of the values changes, the code will break, as values will get mixed as well.

*Hint*: I deliberately named my variable `person_id` instead of `id`, because It's an anti-pattern to shadow built-in variables and/or functions, and it happens that [there's a built-in called id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: You're right. I assumed that this is the exact order as it is in the OP. I edited the answer to reflect this information in a better way.

Comment: dicts being ordered is still an implementation detail in python 3.6. You shouldn't rely on that until 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

You an use `operator.itemgetter()` and `map()`.

```
In [31]: from operator import itemgetter

In [32]: list(map(itemgetter('id', 'name', 'age'), people))
Out[32]: [(1, 'Ada', 55), (2, 'Bart', 46), (3, 'Chloe', 37), (4, 'Dylan', 28)]
```

But note that if you want all the values from all the keys you could simply use `dict.values()` in a list comprehension to get all the respective values.

```
In [33]: [d.values() for d in people]
Out[33]: 
[dict_values([1, 'Ada', 55]),
 dict_values([2, 'Bart', 46]),
 dict_values([3, 'Chloe', 37]),
 dict_values([4, 'Dylan', 28])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for find in people:
    print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(find["id"], find["name"], find["age"]))
```

that will work

Comment: While I am indeed familiar with the conventional method, I'd like to achieve the same result << _Without having to address each dictionary key like `person['key']` but rather by just `key`_ >>

Answer (score 0):

You could build a small class with an `__iter__` method:

```
class Group:
  def __init__(self, d):
     self.__dict__ = d

class People:
   def __init__(self, data):
     self.data = data
   def __iter__(self):
     for i in self.data:
       d = Group(i)
       yield d.id, d.name, d.age

people = [{'age': 55, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Ada'}, {'age': 46, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Bart'}, {'age': 37, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Chloe'}, {'age': 28, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Dylan'}]
for a, b, c in People(people):
   print('{} {} {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Output:

```
1 Ada 55
2 Bart 46
3 Chloe 37
4 Dylan 28
```